# SQL: Splitting first, last and middle name into their own columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How would I go about splitting one column that has the first, last and middle name. To there own separate columns in a SQL Server 2008 query?

The column is called `NAME`

```
NAME(char(25),null)

Mctasrren ,David Max
Cressler ,Patti L
Basil ,Vessen Eddie
Chapplestait ,Victoy
```

this is what i've used so far my main issue is the middle name. or if someone has a better way to shorten the first name code.

--last name code

```
 left([NAME],charindex(' ,',[NAME]))
```

-first name code

```
substring([NAME],charindex(',',[NAME])+1,charindex(' ',substring([NAME],charindex(',',[NAME])+1,25-charindex(',',[NAME])+1)))
```

Comment: So you want someone to give you the answer without any effort on your part.  That's not what SO is about.

Comment: actually rick i been trying.

Comment: nicky i've been able to get the last name using                  left([PA-PT-NAME],charindex(' ,',[NAME]))  it the middle name that really giving my the trouble

Comment: @user2974995 That's good! just show us anything you tried..

Comment: @user2974995 We are not mind readers.  Please share your attempt and we will be glad to help you.  Update your question and add the SQL code.

Comment: How do we know what is last name, middle and first name. I dont see format here. For example last record (Chapplestait) doesnt have middle name or something

Comment: You could `REVERSE` the string and see if there's a space before the comma and extract the FirstName/Initial that way

Comment: The format seems pretty obvious to me: `LastName<space><comma>FirstName<space>MiddleName` with `<space>MiddleName` optional.

Comment: there's a space before the comma

Comment: ok i updated my post with what i've been able to do.The middle name is what im stuck on.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to split it into columns as part of a result set, create computed columns on the table, or actually update the schema to have the data split in the source?

In any case the basic nuts and bolts can be done by either:

1. Use a combination of CHARINDEX, SUBSTRING, and LEFT or RIGHT to find commas or spaces and split around that. If you sure you data will always be 'L_NAME ,F_NAME M_NAME_OR_INITIAL' that will pretty easy. I am actually I surprised I didn't find an similar question here near the top of a google search, but there is an example of similar from [SQLServerCentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1268299-392-1.aspx).
2. Use a RegEx via the CLR, which can be more robust if there is any variety in the data. If you are familiar with RegEx this should be a straight forward parse. Again, a simplified example can found on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9f49d472-678f-49b4-ac9e-d815c97bf6cb/regex-to-parse-or-split-fullname-into-lastname-firstname-middlename?forum=regexp).

Whatever you choose, you'll probably quickly run into names that don't easily follow that format. In that case you want to build more logic into a function handle different types of names.

Comment: +1 for a good explanation and NOT just handing him the answer.  Which I know someone will eventually do.  Asking a question on SO should be your very last option after all else has failed.